# Updating view from service in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

Maybe I am designing this incorrectly ( new to angular ). Currently I have something like this:

`[TVController] depends on [TVService]`

`[TVService] depends on [GameShowChannel] #could possibly have more channels`

In code its something like so:

**html**

```
<div class='tv' ng-controller='TVController' ng-include='currentChannel()> </div>
```

**TVController.js**

```
var TVController = function($scope,TVService){
   $scope.currentChannel = function(){ TVService.currentChannel(); }
}
```

**TVService.js**

```
angular.module('app.service').factory('TVService',function(GameShowChannel){
  return { currentChannel: function(){ GameShowChannel.getView(); }
});
```

**GameShowChannelService.js**

```
angular.module('app.serivce').factory('GameShowChannel',function(){
   return { getView: function(){ './partial/game_show_intro.html'} };
});
```

In `GameShowChannelService.js` I want to be able to update the scope in `game_show_intro.html`. I have a `GameShowIntroController` object in a file, but I am not able to import that into the `GameShowChannelService.js`. Is there a better solution to this problem? Again the problem is that I want to be able to update the view in the `GameShowChannelService`. I want the `GameShowChannelService` to be more than just a static html, but be dynamic so that I can actually 'play' something in that channel. Hope its clear enough.

---

Hmm..Maybe GameShowChannel should be a directive instead?

Another thought would be to broadcast event from service that some state has changed and the GameShowIntroController which controls the game_show_intr.html view, would listen and update to that state accordingly. Would this be a angular approach?

Comment: I think you are right. The GameShowChannel might be better suited for a directive. AngularJS team dictates all DOM manipulations should be in directives. If the initial html is a directive with a model, and the view rendered is dependent on the model, just have your controller change the model which should then in turn cause the directive to change the view.

Comment: Yes, use a custom directive. Services should not be aware of the UI at all. Don't break the nice separation of concerns that Angular gives you!